# Validating Paired Form Fields

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create what I hope is a somewhat simple donation form. There are two options to choose from:

1. A drop down with a text field to enter an amount
2. A text field to write in an other designation along with a text field to enter an amount

I've been looking through a lot of different examples of code, but I'm not entirely sure how to search the technical name for what I need. I need to have an alert appear when nothing is entered as well as an alert when only one part of 1 or one part of 2 is entered. I know this is something I need JS for, but have zero experience with it.

I found several pages that were a little helpful with validation and alert messages for multiple fields, but I think I need to have an either/or type of alert (if that makes sense). EITHER you choose from the drop down and enter an amount OR you enter something in the "Other" text field and enter an amount.

You can see my code below. I included some JS I found and tried to modify that seemed to be closest to what I'm looking for, but with my limited knowledge of the language I know it's not correct (try not to judge me). I can get an alert message that works sometimes and not for everyone. And sometimes the alert still appears when it's filled out correctly.

I feel like my brain is fried at this point, so any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Javascript is definitely going to the top of my "Must Learn" list after this. Thank you!

```js
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["FUND1"].value;
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["FUND2"].value;
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["GIFT_AMOUNT1"].value;
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["GIFT_AMOUNT2"].value;

    if (form1.FUND1.value == '' && form1.FUND2.value == '') {
        alert("Please select a donation designation and an amount.");
        return false;
    }
    if (form1.GIFT_AMOUNT1.value == '' && form1.GIFT_AMOUNT1.value == '') {
        alert("Please select a donation designation and an amount.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="input.php" id="form1"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" >

<div class="giving_dropdown body_copy">
    <h3>Giving Opportunities</h3>
    <select name="FUND1" class="drop_down"  >
        <option value="" selected class="body_copy"></option>
        <option value="Option1" class="body_copy">Option1</option>
        <option value="Option2" class="body_copy">Option2</option>
        <option value="Option3" class="body_copy">Option3</option>
        <option value="Option4" class="body_copy">Option4</option>
        <option value="Option5" class="body_copy">Option5</option>
        <option value="Option6" class="body_copy">Option6</option>
        <option value="Option7" class="body_copy">Option7</option>
        <option value="Option8" class="body_copy">Option8</option>
        <option value="Option9" class="body_copy">Option9</option>
        <option value="Option10" class="body_copy">Option10</option>
        <option value="Option11" class="body_copy">Option11</option>
    </select>
    <input class="inputotherfund" name="GIFT_AMOUNT1" type="text" size="10" id="GIFT_AMOUNT1" value="0.00"/>   
</div>
 
<div class="other_designation">
    <h3>Other</h3>
    <input name="FUND2" type="text" size="50" id="FUND2" class="inputotherfund" placeholder="Indicate where to direct donation"/>
    <input class="inputotherfund" name="GIFT_AMOUNT2" type="text" size="10" id="GIFT_AMOUNT2" value="0.00"/>
</div>
        
<div style="clear:both; float:left;">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Continue" class="continue_button" onclick="validateAndSend()"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an `onclick="validateAndSend()"` in the submit button. This function (`validateAndSend()`) exists in another place? If not, remove this `onclick="validateAndSend()"` from html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is ok.

To improve what you are doing you can try this:

I'm paring FUND and GIFT_AMOUNT because I guess is what you are trying to do, now the alert will show when both 1s or 2s are empty.

```
function validateForm() {
  var form1 = document.forms['form1']

  if (form1.FUND1.value === '' || form1.GIFT_AMOUNT1.value === '') {
    alert("please select a donation designation and an amount 1.");
    return false;
  }
  if (form1.FUND2.value === '' || form1.GIFT_AMOUNT2.value === '') {
    alert("please select a donation designation and an amount 2.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

In your form you need to initialize your GIFT_AMOUNT inputs with `value=""` otherwise if you compare '0.00' with '' always will be `false`.

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="input.php" id="form1"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
  <div class="giving_dropdown body_copy">
    <h3>Giving Opportunities</h3>
    <select name="FUND1" class="drop_down"  >
      <option value="" selected class="body_copy"></option>
      <option value="Option1" class="body_copy">Option1</option>
      <option value="Option2" class="body_copy">Option2</option>
      <option value="Option3" class="body_copy">Option3</option>
      <option value="Option4" class="body_copy">Option4</option>
      <option value="Option5" class="body_copy">Option5</option>
      <option value="Option6" class="body_copy">Option6</option>
      <option value="Option7" class="body_copy">Option7</option>
      <option value="Option8" class="body_copy">Option8</option>
      <option value="Option9" class="body_copy">Option9</option>
      <option value="Option10" class="body_copy">Option10</option>
      <option value="Option11" class="body_copy">Option11</option>
    </select>
    <input class="inputotherfund" name="GIFT_AMOUNT1" type="text" size="10" id="GIFT_AMOUNT1" value="" />
  </div>

  <div class="other_designation">
    <h3>Other</h3>
    <input name="FUND2" type="text" size="50" id="FUND2" class="inputotherfund" placeholder="Indicate where to direct donation" />
    <input class="inputotherfund" name="GIFT_AMOUNT2" type="text" size="10" id="GIFT_AMOUNT2" value="" />
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both; float:left;">
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="continue_button" />
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

There is no need to call a function in your `onclick` property because you are calling the submit function already to improve this behavior you can do something like this:

```
function submitForm() {
  if (validateForm()) {
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

and change the `onsubmit` property from your `form`

```
<form ... onsubmit="submitForm()">
```

If you are starting with javascript will be a good idea to learn how to use the console in order to debug your scripts. [This](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/?hl=en) article is a good point to start and as a last tip check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/debugger) out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response back. I really appreciate the additional learning material. Super helpful! Regarding the code, I'm actually having trouble getting an error message to pop up at all now. Nothing shows up when the fields are blank or partially filled in. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a typo (facepalm) the name of the javascript function is `validateform` instead of `validateForm`. I'm updating the answer. You can try a live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/nakefatece/edit?js,output).

Comment: Oh good catch! That definitely got the message to pop up now. But please don't hate me...now I'm getting the error message for everything. When I have both a fund and an amount entered, I still see the message. Again, I cannot thank you enough for your help. This is one of the things I love about the code world, so many people out there willing to help! It's great!

Comment: Don't worry @CarolineK we're here to help each other ;). Well don't know what to say about your current issue. Did you see any error message in the console?

Comment: by the way if you can share your code [here](https://jsbin.com) I could help you better

Comment: Sure thing. Here's what I have. [link](https://jsbin.com/fuvuvob/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: The last `return` should be `true` in your js code, then everything seems to be correct or what should be the behavior?

Comment: So I changed the return to true but I'm still getting the pop up message even if one of the pairs is filled out. If I fill out both parts of the Giving Opportunities section, it says to fill out the Other section as well. My goal is to have the option of either filling out either the Giving Opportunities section and submitting OR filling out the Other section and submitting. The way it looks now, you have to fill out everything. So sorry for all of the back and forth. I really really appreciate the help! [Here's the link again](https://jsbin.com/subitatani/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Don't worry @CarolineK believe me I'm glad to help, giving a little bit of our time to help people is one of the best things we can do. Well going back to our business here is the [link](https://jsbin.com/hulabesice/edit?js,output) of the achieved code.

Comment: [You. Are. Amazing!](http://78.media.tumblr.com/adf88bc0b267ee195cf2bdb360528825/tumblr_n2rlz6DA9H1qzo384o1_400.gif) This is exactly what I was looking for! I cannot thank you enough for your patience and assistance. I know everyone's time is worth a lot, especially when it comes to coding. It really means a lot that you took so much time to walk through this with me. This is definitely something I am going to learn and help pay the knowledge and kindness forward. Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, what you said remind me the movie *pay it forward* which is one of my favorites because the idea behind that is awesome! It was nice meeting you, until next issue :P